Laravel Echo: Exposing Websocket Keys on the Client-Side
This is my first time posting here, so I apologize if my formatting isn't quite right.
I'm currently working with Laravel Echo to enable real-time event listening on the frontend of my application. Below is the snippet of my echo.js file:
 import Echo from 'laravel-echo';
 import Pusher from 'pusher-js';
 
 window.Pusher = Pusher;
 
 window.Echo = new Echo({
 broadcaster: 'reverb',
 key: process.env.MIX_REVERB_APP_KEY,
 wsHost: process.env.MIX_REVERB_HOST,
 wsPort: process.env.MIX_REVERB_PORT,
 wssPort: process.env.MIX_REVERB_PORT,
 forceTLS: false,
 enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
 });

This script resides in project_name/resources/js/echo.js. To utilize it on the client-side, I need to build it using Laravel Mix, which outputs:
project_name/public/build/assets/app.js
Then, I include it in my frontend like so:
 <script src="{{ asset('build/assets/app.js') }}"></script>
 <script>
 Echo.channel('buttonChannel')
         .listen('ButtonEvent', (event) => {
 document.getElementById('message').innerText += event.message + '\n';
 console.log('Button clicked: ', event.message);
         });
 </script>

However, during inspection (via inspect element), I realized that the Reverb keys and app_id values are exposed. Reverb is the websocket and the broadcaster, which is a first-party of Laravel.
My question is: Is this the correct approach? Should I be allowing my keys to be exposed on the client-side? Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.
